# tex4ht gives \catcode`\^^ error when loading mathtools

Tags: tex4ht, mathtools

I do not know if this is new error, caused by latest TL update. But this is first time I see it.

This MWE compiles with no problem with lualatex, but gives

```
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ts1cmr.fd) (/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphicx.sty (/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/tex4ht/graphics-hooks.4ht) (/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphics.sty
! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again>
^
l.39 \catcode`\^^
               A=\catcode`\%
?
```

When compiled with tex4ht.   This is the smallest example I could make it to show the error. The Latex is auto-generated.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath} 
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
\frac{1}{18} \, \sqrt{3} \log\left(\frac{{\left| 6 \, x - 2 \, \sqrt{3} \right|}}
  {{\left| 6 \, x + 2 \, \sqrt{3} \right|}}\right) - \frac{1}{18} \, \sqrt{3} 
  \log\left(-\frac{{\left| -6 \, x - 8 \, \sqrt{3} + 6 \, \sqrt{x^{2} + 1} - \frac{6}{x - \sqrt{x^{2} + 1}} \right|}}
  {2 \, {\left(3 \, x - 4 \, \sqrt{3} - 3 \, \sqrt{x^{2} + 1} + \frac{3}{x - \sqrt{x^{2} + 1}}\right)}}\right) 
  - \frac{4 \, {\left(x - \sqrt{x^{2} + 1} + \frac{1}{x - \sqrt{x^{2} + 1}}\right)}}
  {3 \, {\left(3 \, {\left(x - \sqrt{x^{2} + 1} + 
  \frac{1}{x - \sqrt{x^{2} + 1}}\right)}^{2} - 16\right)}} - \frac{4 \, x}{3 \, {\left(3 \, x^{2} - 1\right)}}
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

And now I compile using:

```
make4ht -ulm default -a debug foo5.tex "htm"
```

it gives

```
(base) >make4ht -ulm default -a debug foo5.tex "htm"
[INFO]    mkparams: Output dir:
[INFO]    mkparams: Compiler: dvilualatex
[INFO]    mkparams: Latex options: -jobname=foo5
[INFO]    mkparams: tex4ht.sty: xhtml,htm,charset=utf-8
[INFO]    mkparams: tex4ht:  -cmozhtf -utf8
[INFO]    mkparams: build_file: foo5.mk4
[INFO]    mkparams: Output format: html5
[STATUS]  make4ht: Conversion started
[STATUS]  make4ht: Input file: foo5.tex
[INFO]    mkutils: Load extension       common_domfilters
[INFO]    mkutils: Cannot open config file      foo5.mk4
[INFO]    make4ht-lib: setting param correct_exit
[INFO]    make4ht-lib: setting param correct_exit
[INFO]    make4ht-lib: setting param correct_exit
[INFO]    make4ht-lib: setting param ext
[INFO]    make4ht-lib: Adding:  ext     dvi
[INFO]    htlatex: LaTeX call: dvilualatex --interaction=errorstopmode -jobname=foo5   '\makeatletter\def\HCode{\futurelet\HCode\HChar}\def\HChar{\ifx"\HCode\def\HCode"##1"{\Link##1}\expandafter\HCode\else\expandafter\Link\fi}\def\Link#1.a.b.c.{\g@addto@macro\@documentclasshook{\RequirePackage[#1,html]{tex4ht}}\let\HCode\documentstyle\def\documentstyle{\let\documentstyle\HCode\expandafter\def\csname tex4ht\endcsname{#1,html}\def\HCode####1{\documentstyle[tex4ht,}\@ifnextchar[{\HCode}{\documentstyle[tex4ht]}}}\makeatother\HCode xhtml,htm,charset=utf-8,html5.a.b.c.\input "\detokenize{foo5.tex}"'
This is LuaTeX, Version 1.12.0 (TeX Live 2020)
 restricted system commands enabled.
LaTeX2e <2020-10-01> patch level 2


L3 programming layer <2020-12-07> xparse <2020-03-03> (./foo5.tex (/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2020/04/10 v1.4m Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size11.clo)) (/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/tex4ht/tex4ht.sty) (/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/tex4ht/usepackage.4ht) (/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsmath.sty
For additional information on amsmath, use the `?' option.
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amstext.sty (/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsgen.sty)) (/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsbsy.sty) (/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsopn.sty)) (/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/mathtools/mathtools.sty (/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty) (/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/calc.sty) (/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/mathtools/mhsetup.sty)) (/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/tex4ht/tex4ht.4ht
::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
 TeX4ht info is available in the log file
::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
) (/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/tex4ht/tex4ht.sty
--- needs --- tex4ht foo5 ---
(./foo5.tmp) (./foo5.xref) (/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/tex4ht/html4.4ht) (/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/tex4ht/unicode.4ht) (/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/tex4ht/html4-math.4ht) (/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/tex4ht/html5.4ht) (/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/tex4ht/html4.4ht) (/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/tex4ht/unicode.4ht) (/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/tex4ht/html4-math.4ht) (/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/tex4ht/html5.4ht) (/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/tex4ht/latex.4ht (/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/fontenc.sty (/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/lm/ot1lmr.fd)) (/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/kastrup/binhex.tex) (/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/tuenc.def) (/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/tex4ht/tuenc-luatex.4ht
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/luatex/luatexbase/luatexbase.sty (/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/luatex/ctablestack/ctablestack.sty)) (/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/lualatex/luacode/luacode.sty (/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/iftex/ifluatex.sty (/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/iftex/iftex.sty))) (/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/tex4ht/html4.4ht) (/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/tex4ht/unicode.4ht) (/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/tex4ht/html4-math.4ht) (/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/tex4ht/html5.4ht)) (/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/tex4ht/html4.4ht) (/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/tex4ht/unicode.4ht) (/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/tex4ht/html4-math.4ht) (/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/tex4ht/html5.4ht) (/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/tex4ht/html4.4ht)
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/tex4ht/unicode.4ht) (/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/tex4ht/html4-math.4ht) (/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/tex4ht/html5.4ht)) (/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/tex4ht/fontmath.4ht (/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/tex4ht/html4.4ht) (/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/tex4ht/unicode.4ht) (/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/tex4ht/html4-math.4ht) (/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/tex4ht/html5.4ht)) (/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/tex4ht/article.4ht (/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/tex4ht/html4.4ht) (/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/tex4ht/unicode.4ht) (/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/tex4ht/html4-math.4ht) (/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/tex4ht/html5.4ht)) (/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/tex4ht/amsmath.4ht
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/tex4ht/html4.4ht) (/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/tex4ht/unicode.4ht) (/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/tex4ht/html4-math.4ht) (/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/tex4ht/html5.4ht)) (/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/tex4ht/amstext.4ht (/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/tex4ht/html4.4ht) (/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/tex4ht/unicode.4ht) (/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/tex4ht/html4-math.4ht) (/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/tex4ht/html5.4ht)) (/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/tex4ht/amsbsy.4ht (/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/tex4ht/html4.4ht) (/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/tex4ht/unicode.4ht) (/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/tex4ht/html4-math.4ht) (/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/tex4ht/html5.4ht))
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/tex4ht/amsopn.4ht (/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/tex4ht/html4.4ht) (/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/tex4ht/unicode.4ht) (/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/tex4ht/html4-math.4ht) (/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/tex4ht/html5.4ht)) (/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/tex4ht/mathtools.4ht (/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/tex4ht/html4.4ht) (/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/tex4ht/unicode.4ht) (/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/tex4ht/html4-math.4ht) (/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/tex4ht/html5.4ht)) (/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/tex4ht/html4.4ht) (/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/tex4ht/unicode.4ht) (/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/tex4ht/html4-math.4ht) (/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/tex4ht/html5.4ht))
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3backend/l3backend-dvips.def) (./foo5.aux) (/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ts1cmr.fd) (/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphicx.sty (/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/tex4ht/graphics-hooks.4ht) (/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphics.sty
! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again>
^
l.39 \catcode`\^^
               A=\catcode`\%
?
```

When removing the `\usepackage{mathtools}` package, it compiles OK. No errors.  TL fully updated 3-4 days ago.

```
make4ht --version
make4ht version v0.3f

which tex4ht
/usr/local/texlive/2020/bin/x86_64-linux/tex4ht
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Edit:*

I've found the source of this issue. TeX4ht redefines `\@begindocumenthook` and executes some code before and after it. `\@begindocumenthook` contained code that is added using `\AtBeginDocument`. It was deprecated by the new LaTeX hook system. Because it is not used anymore, TeX4ht code that handled `\AtBeginDocument` is not executed, which results in this catcode clash.

This issue can be fixed by using the hook system to execute the TeX4ht handling of `\AtBeginDocument`. I've fixed it in TeX4ht sources already. In the meantime, you can emulate it using the following `.cfg` file:

```
\Preamble{xhtml}
\AddToHook{begindocument/before}[tex4ht]{\csname a:AtBeginDocument\endcsname}
\AddToHook{begindocument/end}[tex4ht]{\csname b:AtBeginDocument\endcsname}
\begin{document}
\EndPreamble
```

*Original answer:*

Mathtools loads the `graphicx` package in `\AtBeginDocument`. It is loaded after package `.4ht` files had been processed and there is some catcode clash, it seems.

The simplest fix is to load `graphicx` package in your document, as Egreg showed. Fix on the TeX4ht side is to load `graphicx` in `mathtools.4ht`:

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% mathtools.4ht                         2009-05-21-09:32 %
% Copyright (C) 2007--2009       Eitan M. Gurari         %
%                                                        %
% This work may be distributed and/or modified under the %
% conditions of the LaTeX Project Public License, either %
% version 1.3c of this license or (at your option) any   %
% later version. The latest version of this license is   %
% in                                                     %
%   http://www.latex-project.org/lppl.txt                %
% and version 1.3c or later is part of all distributions %
% of LaTeX version 2005/12/01 or later.                  %
%                                                        %
% This work has the LPPL maintenance status "maintained".%
%                                                        %
% This Current Maintainer of this work                   %
% is Eitan M. Gurari.                                    %
%                                                        %
% If you modify this program your changing its signature %
% with a directive of the following form will be         %
% appreciated.                                           %
%            \message{signature}                         %
%                                                        %
%                             gurari@cse.ohio-state.edu  %
%                 http://www.cse.ohio-state.edu/~gurari  %
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\immediate\write-1{version 2009-05-21-09:32}

\@ifpackageloaded{graphicx}{}{\RequirePackage{graphicx}}

\ifx \o:endgathered:\:UnDef\else
   \HRestore\endgathered
\fi
\def\shortintertext{\intertext}
\def\:tempc#1#2{{\csname a:prescript\endcsname}\sp{#1}\sb{#2}}
\expandafter\HLet\csname prescript \endcsname=\:tempc
\NewConfigure{prescript}{1}
\Configure{prescript}{\HCode{<mrow class="prescript"></mrow>}}
\renewenvironment{dcases}[1][c]{%
  \RIfM@\else
      \nonmatherr@{\begin{\@currenvir}}%
  \fi
  \left\lbrace
  \vcenter \bgroup
      \Let@ \chardef\dspbrk@context\@ne \restore@math@cr
      \spread@equation
      \ialign\bgroup
        \strut@$\m@th\displaystyle{##}$\hfil&\quad$\m@th\displaystyle{##}$\hfil\strut@
        \crcr
}
{\endaligned\right.}
                                    \catcode`\#13 \catcode`\!6
\def\reg:dcases[!1]{%
  \RIfM@\else
      \nonmatherr@{\begin{dcases}}%
  \fi
  \vcenter\bgroup
    \Let@ \chardef\dspbrk@context\@ne \restore@math@cr
    \SaveMkHalignConf:g{dcases}%
    \MkHalign#{$\m@th\displaystyle{\HCode{}}#$&\quad$\m@th\displaystyle{\HCode{}}#$}%
}
                                    \catcode`\#=6 \catcode`\!=12
\def\:tempc{\crcr\EndMkHalign
    \RecallMkHalignConfig \egroup\b:dcases \right.}
\HLet\enddcases\:tempc
\def\:temp{\left\lbrace   \pic:MkHalign{dcases}}
\expandafter\HLet\csname \string\dcases\endcsname\:temp
\NewConfigure{dcases}{6}
\renewenvironment{dcases*}[1][c]{%
  \RIfM@\else
      \nonmatherr@{\begin{\@currenvir}}%
  \fi
  \left\lbrace
  \vcenter \bgroup
      \Let@ \chardef\dspbrk@context\@ne \restore@math@cr
      \spread@equation
      \ialign\bgroup
        \strut@$\m@th\displaystyle{##}$\hfil&\quad{##}\hfil\strut@
        \crcr
}
{\endaligned\right.}
                                    \catcode`\#13 \catcode`\!6
\expandafter\def\csname reg:dcases*\endcsname[!1]{%
  \RIfM@\else
      \nonmatherr@{\begin{dcases*}}%
  \fi
  \vcenter\bgroup
    \Let@ \chardef\dspbrk@context\@ne \restore@math@cr
    \SaveMkHalignConf:g{dcases*}%
    \MkHalign#{$\m@th\displaystyle{\HCode{}}#$\quad&#}%
}
                                    \catcode`\#=6 \catcode`\!=12
\def\:tempc{\crcr\EndMkHalign
    \RecallMkHalignConfig \egroup\csname b:dcases*\endcsname \right.}
\expandafter\HLet\csname enddcases*\endcsname\:tempc
\def\:temp{\left\lbrace   \pic:MkHalign{dcases*}}
\expandafter\HLet\csname \string\dcases*\endcsname\:temp
\NewConfigure{dcases*}{6}

\edef\cat:underscore{%
   \noexpand\catcode`\noexpand\_=\the\catcode`\_ }
\catcode`\_=11
\def\MT_gathered_pre:{}
      \def\MT_gathered_post:{}
      \def\MT_gathered_env_end:{}
                                    \catcode`\#13 \catcode`\!6
\def\reg:MT_gathered_env[!1]{%
  \RIfM@\else
      \nonmatherr@{\begin{MT_gathered_env}}%
  \fi
  \null  \vcenter\bgroup
    \Let@ \chardef\dspbrk@context\@ne \restore@math@cr
    \SaveMkHalignConf:g{MT_gathered_env}%
\MkHalign#{$\m@th\displaystyle{\HCode{}}#$}%
}
                                    \catcode`\#=6 \catcode`\!=12
\def\:tempc{\crcr\EndMkHalign
    \RecallMkHalignConfig \egroup\b:MT_gathered_env}
\HLet\endMT_gathered_env\:tempc
\def\:temp{\pic:MkHalign{MT_gathered_env}}
\expandafter\HLet\csname \string\MT_gathered_env\endcsname\:temp
\NewConfigure{MT_gathered_env}{6}
\def\:tempc#1#2{{\m@th#1{#2}}}
\HLet\MT_cramped_internal:Nn\:tempc

\cat:underscore
\Hinput{mathtools}
\endinput
```

The document is processed without errors with this fix.

Comment: tex4ht seems to change the catcode of ^ to 12, is this needed?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer handling of sub and superscripts is pretty complicated in TeX4ht, it changes their catcodes when `.4ht` files are processed, as it does various tricks at that moment.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I've found the issue, please see the updated answer.

Comment: ah, good find. I hadn't the time to look, but I suspected that some resetting code didn't work anymore.

Answer (score 2):

The error happens during loading of `graphics.sty`. I'm not sure why this happens, but a workaround is to load `graphicx` *before* `mathtools`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}
test
\begin{align*} a&=b\\c&=d\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

What's the problem? That `mathtools` does

```
\AtBeginDocument{\RequirePackage{graphicx}...}
```

which is incorrect and should be

```
\RequirePackage{graphicx}
\AtBeginDocument{...}
```

On the other hand `tex4ht` makes `^` into a math active character, hence with category code 12. Loading a package with “strange” category codes can lead to unexpected results.

So, in my opinion, `mathtools` and `tex4ht` are linked in a conspiracy and both should fix the respective problems; `mathtools` should load the package earlier and `tex4ht` should change category codes as late as possible.

Comment: mathtools loads graphicx at begin document (no idea why ...), and tex4ht has reset the catcode of ^ to 12 there (no idea why too ...)

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I'm not sure why `mathtools` loads `graphicx` at begin document in the first place. With `tex4ht` the `^` is made into a math active character (they surely have reasons to).

Comment: perhaps they load graphicx late to avoid an option clash error.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Well, then it should be done at end preamble rather than at begin document.

Comment: yes, but probably the end preamble hook didn't exist at the time the code was written ;-)

Comment: Ulrike is correct. And at the time only atbegindocument was available

Comment: @UlrikeFischer they even _document_ that as the reason % \changes{v1.08b}{2010/07/21}{Moved graphicx loading down here such
% that we do not get into option clash problems}